# Magento2 : display static blocks in home page

Tags: magento2

How to display static blocks in the home page. I want to show a static block on the home page.I am overriding module_cms and add this code in cms_index-index but it's showing only last block

```
<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block1</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>

  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier" after="-">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block2</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>
```

How to show all blocks

Comment: You can set using page as well as layout file. Using Page you can set anywhere inside homepage and its easy to manage compare to layout file.

Comment: cms page?  Rakesh

Comment: Yes using cms page, call block inside cms page

Comment: how to call cms page in homepage.. can you give any example

Comment: how to display it in home page

Comment: you have to keep cms_index_index.xml file

Comment: I added in that file only Rakesh but it shows only last block

Comment: plz check my updated answer. Let me know if you have any issue

Comment: Worked for you below method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep below XML in your cms_index_index.xml file and check-in front,

You have to keep the same `block_identifier` for both static blocks.

**`You have to keep static block name as unique,`**

```
  <referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block1</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier-second" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
   </referenceContainer>
```

**Replace block1 and block2 with your static block id in above XML code.**

Comment: nothing showing

Comment: have you changed name same as above and have you create block1 and block2?

Comment: changed but not showing

Comment: ok i got it its working

Comment: if i add another block then

Comment: Yes you have to first create static block and assign block id to block1 and block2 in above example. I have checked this

Comment: no iam asking how to give "after"

Comment: you can set your block position using after="blockname" if you want to your block appear after some block then you have to give block name in after value if you keep "-" then this block will come after all block of same container.

Answer (score 31):

You can do it in 2 ways.

From cms page add block to homage:

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

From Xml File:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: which xml file ..Kul

Comment: @Nadh `cms_index_index.xml` you can find it in view section of module-cms

Comment: need to overide that module?

Comment: If you don't have this module in your theme you can copy from `Vendor/magento/` otherwise no need to override

Comment: its not working

Comment: Please update question with code you have applied. have you replace `block_identifier` wtith identifier of your block?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49662/discussion-between-kul-and-nadh).

Comment: I am creating whole theme from blank theme, which practice is best?

Answer (score 4):

**Create Block**

1. Go to the **Admin Panel** of the Magento Store and navigate to the **Content** tab from the left corner of the page. Next, click the **Blocks** option.
2. Then click **Add New Block**.
3. Next, add the **details of the Block** -> Enter the **Block Title** (Title of the Block) and
   **Block Identifier** (Id of the Block).
4. Set **Block Identifier=Demo_Test** and add some text in **content** section.
5. Now just click **Save**.

**Add Block to Homepage**

1. Go to the **Admin Panel** of the Magento store, navigate to the **Content** tab from the left corner of the page and then click on the Page option.
2. Click the **Edit** on the **homepage**.
3. Go to the **content** section and add **block shortcode** : 
   `{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="Demo_Test"}}`
4. Click **Save**

Comment: need to add url as home?

Comment: Which URL you are talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is, go to the layout file and copy the block description

`<block class="Itheavens\Fanpage\Block\Index\Index" name="index.index" template="Itheavens_Fanpage::index/index.phtml"/>`

and replace it with second bracket be like this

```
{{block class="Itheavens\Fanpage\Block\Index\Index" name="index.index" template="Itheavens_Fanpage::index/index.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

block_identifier

Add in default.xml file under Magento_theme Folder which is placed under current applied theme.