# How to show static block just below navigation?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, static-block

**I want to show a discount bar just below navigation**

- Created a static block and placed my content inside it .
- Called block using below code

> {{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="discount-bar"}}

Its appearing on front end but I want it to place just below navigation and then after my slider

I have gone through this [Magento2 : display static blocks in home page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149022/magento2-display-static-blocks-in-home-page)

**If possible without using XML then will be great help**

Comment: Are you using default theme

Comment: luma extended , I mean custom theme based on luma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to add static blocks on Homepage and setting there order is:

> creating blocks and widgets

- You need to **create a widget** , name it **discount bar**
- select  your static block ( discount-bar ) from widget options
- Assign store view and set order for example " 1 "
- Add layout update Display on specified page / Page: CMS HOME PAGE / Container: After page header

for more details you can check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187029/54588

**Note :** Set order no in desired way , like in your case for discount bar " 1 " and for slider " 2 "

I hope this will help you in most easy way