# How to get review rating and stars in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, php

I have this piece of code found on StackExchange, to show all the reviews from a store store view.
And it works great!
But how can I extend it to also show the rating and stars for each review?

Thank you,

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_reviewsColFactory = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
$_storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$reviewsCollection = $_reviewsColFactory->create()
->addStoreFilter($_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId())
->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder();

foreach($reviewsCollection as $review):?>
<div class='review-single col-md-12'>
    <div class="box-review-single">
        <h4 id="title-review"><?php echo $review['title'];  ?></h4>
        <span>Rating and Stars</span>
        <p id="detail-review"><em><?php echo $review['detail'];  ?></em></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**UPDATE**

@Msquare

This is the code I'm trying:

```
<?php
protected $_storeManager;
protected $_reviewsCollection;
protected $ratingAttributeFactory;
protected $ratingFactory;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Option\Vote\CollectionFactory $ratingFactory,
\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\CollectionFactory $ratingAttributeFactory

) {
$this->_reviewsColFactory = $collectionFactory;
$this->ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
$this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
$this->ratingAttributeFactory = $ratingAttributeFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
echo "<pre>";
$review_collection = $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
)->setDateOrder();
$final_rate_value = [];
$default_rate_value = [];
$finalRatingData = [];
// get All Reviews
foreach ($review_collection as $reviewKey => $reviewValue) {
    // get review enable label name
    $ratingAttribute_collection = $this->ratingAttributeFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $rating_collection = $this->ratingFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('review_id', $reviewValue->getId());
    $x = 0;
    // get rating values
    $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['id'] = $reviewValue->getId();
    $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['title'] = $reviewValue->getTitle();
    $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['detail'] = $reviewValue->getDetail();
    $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['nickname'] = $reviewValue->getNickname();
    $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['entity_id'] = $reviewValue->getEntityId();
    $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['status_id'] = $reviewValue->getStatusId();
    foreach ($rating_collection as $ratingKey => $ratingValue) {
        // get rating label name
        foreach ($ratingAttribute_collection as $rat_attribute_key => $rat_attribute_value) {
            if ($ratingValue->getRatingId() == $rat_attribute_value->getRatingId()) {
                $final_rate_value[$reviewValue->getId()][$rat_attribute_value->getRatingCode()] = $ratingValue->getPercent();
                $default_rate_value[$reviewValue->getId()][$ratingValue->getRatingId()] = $rat_attribute_value->getRatingCode();
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach ($final_rate_value as $final_rateKey => $final_rateValue) {
    if (!empty($final_rateValue)) {
        foreach ($final_rateValue as $FinalKey => $finalValue) {
            if ($finalValue == 20) {
                $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
            } elseif ($finalValue == 40) {
                $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
            } elseif ($finalValue == 60) {
                $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
            } elseif ($finalValue == 80) {
                $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
            } elseif ($finalValue == 100) {
                $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;';
            } else {
                $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
            }

        }
    }
}
echo "Your Rating Star Data <br/>";
print_r($finalRatingData);
exit();
}
?>
```

--- UPDATE No 2 ---

I have come so far, that I don't have any more error messages, but nothing is shown where I include the phtml-file in a CMS.

In the following file:

`\app\design\frontend\Smartwave\alldogroup\Magento_Review\layout\default.xml`

I have this:

`<block class="AlldoGroup\AllReviews\Block" name="show_all_reviews"   template="magento_review::allreviews.phtml" cacheable="false"/>`

And on the CMS home page I have:

`{{block class="AlldoGroup\AllReviews\Block\AllReviews" template="magento_review::allreviews.phtml"}}`

The Block path to AllReviews.php are:

`\app\code\AlldoGroup\AllReviews\Block\AllReviews.php`

Is this correct?

Comment: use Magento_Review instead of magento_review.

Comment: Seems to be working now :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Add Block to your Layout**

```
   <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\AllReviews"
          name="show_all_reviews"
          template="VendoreName_ModuleName::allreviews.phtml"
          cacheable="false"/>
```

> **Add allreviews.phtml file at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

```
<?php
$reviewData = $block->getAllRatingData();
foreach ($reviewData as $reviewKey => $reviewValue) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($reviewValue);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
    <div class='review-single col-md-12'>
        <div class="box-review-single">
            <h4 id="title-review"><?php echo $reviewValue['title'];  ?></h4>
            <span>Rating and Stars</span>
            <p id="detail-review"><em><?php echo $reviewValue['detail'];  ?></em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

> **Add AllReviews.php file at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class AllReviews extends Template
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_localeCurrency;
    protected $_reviewsCollection;
    protected $ratingAttributeFactory;
    protected $ratingFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Option\Vote\CollectionFactory $ratingFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\CollectionFactory $ratingAttributeFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_reviewsColFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->ratingAttributeFactory = $ratingAttributeFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getAllRatingData()
    {
        $review_collection = $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();
        $final_rate_value = [];
        $default_rate_value = [];
        $finalRatingData = [];
        // get All Reviews
        foreach ($review_collection as $reviewKey => $reviewValue) {
            // get review enable label name
            $ratingAttribute_collection = $this->ratingAttributeFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
            $rating_collection = $this->ratingFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('review_id', $reviewValue->getId());
            $x = 0;
            // get rating values
            $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['id'] = $reviewValue->getId();
            $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['title'] = $reviewValue->getTitle();
            $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['detail'] = $reviewValue->getDetail();
            $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['nickname'] = $reviewValue->getNickname();
            $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['entity_id'] = $reviewValue->getEntityId();
            $finalRatingData[$reviewValue->getId()]['status_id'] = $reviewValue->getStatusId();
            foreach ($rating_collection as $ratingKey => $ratingValue) {
                // get rating label name
                foreach ($ratingAttribute_collection as $rat_attribute_key => $rat_attribute_value) {
                    if ($ratingValue->getRatingId() == $rat_attribute_value->getRatingId()) {
                        $final_rate_value[$reviewValue->getId()][$rat_attribute_value->getRatingCode()] = $ratingValue->getPercent();
                        $default_rate_value[$reviewValue->getId()][$ratingValue->getRatingId()] = $rat_attribute_value->getRatingCode();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($final_rate_value as $final_rateKey => $final_rateValue) {
            if (!empty($final_rateValue)) {
                foreach ($final_rateValue as $FinalKey => $finalValue) {
                    if ($finalValue == 20) {
                        $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
                    } elseif ($finalValue == 40) {
                        $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
                    } elseif ($finalValue == 60) {
                        $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
                    } elseif ($finalValue == 80) {
                        $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
                    } elseif ($finalValue == 100) {
                        $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;';
                    } else {
                        $finalRatingData[$final_rateKey][$FinalKey] = '&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;&#9734;&nbsp;';
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return $finalRatingData;
    }
}
```

[*Click Here to download*](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KeD1F2ECbaHj5-CjOuzhJkc6FitHdqs3?usp=sharing)

> **Use into CMS page {{block class="Test\Blog\Block\AllReviews" name="test" template="Test_Blog::allreviews.phtml"}}**

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thanks, trying your code, but we get the following error:

`[2020-12-08 12:50:21] main.CRITICAL: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED), expecting end of file in app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Review/templates/allreviews.phtml:22`

Please advise,

Comment: Please share your updated file code into your question for more detail.

Comment: Did a update on the original post above, where you can se the code. Thanks.

Comment: Add above files and run magento upgrade command. you must add block to your layout. Please check and update me.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid it doesn't work.
I have done exactly as you described.
I'm getting this error:

`"We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content."`

Maybe I need to create a extension instead?
What should the name of the layout file be? 
`show_all_reviews.xml`?

Comment: Before run please run magento commnad php bin/magento setup:upgrade. where you want to show all reviews ? Yes you can create extension.

Comment: First I ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then deploy. I also ran `cache:flush`. I want to be able to run it on any CMS page.

Comment: Yes you can use into any CMS page. just add  {{block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\AllReviews" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::allreviews.phtml"}} https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200387/82670